# Query to show dates that are missed in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is using SQL Server 2019

Difficult to explain; I have two tables:

DATES:

| DATE |
| --- |
| 01/01/2022 |
| 02/01/2022 |

INSURANCE_COVER:

| INSURANCE_COVER_ID | INSURANCE_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/01/2022 |
| 1 | 03/01/2022 |
| 2 | 31/12/2021 |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 |

I need to get all rows from `INSURANCE_COVER` where the `INSURANCE_COVER_ID` does not have a `INSURANCE_DATE` in `DATES` and I need the missing `DATE` to show.

I need the returned results to look like this:

| DATE | INSURANCE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 |
| 02/01/2022 | 2 |

I have only been able to do this with a while loop, but the performance is awful.

Comment: Not sure this needs a calendar table; a `CROSS JOIN` between your dates and the (distinct) values of `INSURANCE_COVER_ID` would give you a dataset you could then `LEFT JOIN` to your `INSURANCE_COVER` table and then you just need to return rows where no row was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build the list of desired values with a **cross join**, and then use an **exclusion join** to find what is missing from that set:

```
SELECT d.[Date], IDs.INSURANCE_COVER_ID
FROM [dates] d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT INSURANCE_COVER_ID FROM INSURANCE_COVER) IDs
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE_COVER C ON C.INSURANCE_COVER_ID = IDs.INSURANCE_COVER_ID
    AND C.Insurance_Date = d.[Date]
WHERE C.INSURANCE_COVER_ID IS NULL
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d26d09494a0d6b06623a35610170c8eb

We could probably make this even faster with a `NOT EXISTS()` instead of an exclusion join, but my personal history is I find it much easier and faster to write the exclusion join, and the performance difference doesn't always justify the additional initial time investment.

---

As a side note, the date formats in that data are **WRONG**. Different languages and cultures expect dates formatted in different ways. Some like MM/dd/yyyy. Some like dd-MM-yyyy. Others might prefer yyyy-MM-dd.

The SQL language is no different: it has it's own expectations around how dates should look, and when writing for SQL **you should use that format.** When writing a date value with no time, it looks like this: `yyyyMMdd` (note the complete lack of separators in addition to the ordering). When including a time value, it looks like this: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`.